# Why to create Custom Notification Broadcast Center in iOS

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

In some projects I often see that people create their own custom `NotificationCenter`(they create their own Notification Broadcasting mechanism which behaves similar to the `NSNotificationCenter`) instead of using Apple's `NSNotificationCentre`. Can anyone please tell me the reason behind this? Why cant we use `NSNotificationCenter` directly instead of building our own? Also can you please tell the scenarios where we need to do this?

Comment: You can use `NotificationCenter` directly. If you want to know why specific projects/people create a different mechanism, you'll have to ask them, or at least post links here so we know what projects you're talking about.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks a lot for the response. Unfortunately I am unable to post the code here because I don't have access to it right now and to the people who wrote it.